# Zermelo theorem implies Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

**Definitions** $\mathbf{1.}$ If $f$ a function and for all $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$, $f(x) \in x$, we say $f$ is a selective function.

$\mathbf{2.}$ ($\textit{Zermelo theorem.}$) If $A$ is a set, then exists a injective function $f$ such that $\operatorname{rang} f=A$ and $\operatorname{dom} f$ is an ordinal number.

$\mathbf{3.}$ (Axiom of choice). Exists a selective function $f$ such that $\operatorname{dom} f = \textit{U}-\{0\}$ where $U$ is the universe class.

**Problem** Zermelo theorem implies axiom of choice.

Let $U-\{0\}$ a set then by Zermelo theorem, exists a injective function $f$ such that $\operatorname{rang} f = U-\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{dom} f$ is an ordinal number. Then $\operatorname{dom} f^{-1}=\operatorname{rang} f = U -\{0\}$. Its enough to prove $f^{-1}$ is a selective function, we have $f^{-1}$ is a function.And, let

$x \in \operatorname{dom}f^{-1}$ then $x \in \operatorname{rang} f$, because $\operatorname{dom}f^{-1}=\operatorname{rang} f$ then $\exists y \text{ such that } f(y)=x$.

I don't know how I should use $\operatorname{dom} f$ is an ordinal number. Could you give me to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

You are well-ordering the wrong set. You should be well-ordering $\bigcup U$ instead. To understand why, try it with $U=\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. Namely, try producing a choice function from all non-empty sets of $\Bbb N$.